# Quick Probability Concept: N-bit strings

Tags: computer-science, probability, probability-theory

Suppose you generate an N-bit string (composed of only 1's and 0's). 
The sum of all of these 0's and 1's is X. 
What is the probability that X is odd, if N is odd?
What is the probability that X is odd if N is even?

Since the chance of any bit being a 0 or 1 is 50%, I would just assume that both answers are 50%. 
However, I don't this is quite right. Can I get some ideas on how to solve this problem?
any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Off-topic, but I'll bite:

How many possible length-N strings are there?  How many of them have an even bit-sum?  How many of them have an odd bit-sum?

To put it another way, assume there are `a` even length-(N-1) strings, and `b` odd length-(N-1) strings.  To form a length-N string, append either a 0 or 1.  This results in `a+b` even strings, and `a+b` odd strings.

Comment: There should be 2^n possible N-length strings, and if we only take odd or even strings this would be 2^(n-1), correct?

Comment: sorry, I'm having trouble connecting the dots here. Am I using induction to support my 50% theory, or using it to somehow get a different answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is a **50% chance** that X is odd.

If N is 1, the only possible strings are 0 and 1, so there's a 50% chance that X is odd.

The possible strings when N=2 are the strings of N=1 with either 0 or 1 appended: 00, 01, 10, 11.  Since the odds are already 50% for N=1, and the odds are 50% for the digit being added, the odds for N=2 are 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right. Maybe it might be useful to see this formally.

The bits, which are 0 and 1 with probability 1/2, are random variables of the Bernoulli distribution of parameter p=1/2. The sum of N independent Bernoulli random variables of parameter follows (by definition) a Binomial distribution, with parameters (N,p). Thus your sum is a Binomial distribution with parameter (N,1/2).

See [Wikipedia's page on the Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Now the probability P that the number is (say) even is:

```
P = Sum[Binomial[n,k]*1/2^n,k=all even values between 0 and n]

P = Sum[Binomial[n, 2 k]*1/2^n, k=0..Floor[n/2]]

P = 1/2 * Sum[Binomial[Floor[n/2],k]*1/2^n, k=0..Floor[n/2]]
```

And that sum is well known to be equal to one (it's [Newton's binomial formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)), so you're left with

```
P = 1/2
```

This question would have been more appropriate on [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), and by that I mean that I would have been able to use LaTeX in the answer :)